# Grails RestBuilder sending weird JSON

Tags: json, grails

I've recently upgraded my project's grails version from 2.3.6 to 2.5.0 in order to use a version that is compliant with Java 8.  I upgraded quite a few plugin version to work with with the upgraded Grails version. However the RestBuilder is acting funky. Instead of sending the regular JSON object that it was before, it is wrapping it in the actual object (i.e. `{"target": {"var1":"value", "var2":"value"}, "prettyPrint": true}` ).

Here are my dependencies:

```
    plugins {
    //runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.1.2"
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.14"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.14"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":httplogger:1.1"

    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

    build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"

    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC5"
    compile ":rest-client-builder:2.1.1"
}
```

and here is the code:

```
def createCustomer(Customer customer, String customerId) {

    def enrollmentResponse = new CustomerEnrollmentResponse()
    def customerJson = customer as JSON
    def partnerKey = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser().partnerKey
    def baseUrl = grailsApplication.config.rest.baseUrl
    String url = "${baseUrl}${customerApiContextUrl}${partnerKey}/${customerId}"
    def resp = new RestBuilder().post(url) {
        contentType: "application/json"
        json: customerJson
    }
    enrollmentResponse.responseCode = resp.status
    if (enrollmentResponse.responseCode != 200) {
        enrollmentResponse.error = new APIError(resp.json)
    }
    return enrollmentResponse
}
```

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: Its hard to identify without knowing what `CustomerEnrollmentResponse` or `APIError` does or what is the value in `resp.json`. But if you are sure that everytime this ame thing happens then you can modify the return to respond correctly.

Comment: The problem is that the code is SENDING a wrapped object, not receiving it. I'm not having a problem receiving the object, it's the sending of it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "AS JSON"

Instead use

```
JsonBuilder json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(data)

json.toString()
```

That will give you the exact JSON value

Answer (score 0):

I have added following dependencies to build config and it worked for me

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.0'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.0'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.0'
```

Answer (score -2):

The default groovy json library has some issues.

If were you i would use jackson library, which is the best json library.

Regards.